# "No executable found matching command" exception when running "docker run"

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I am a newbie to docker, I have a simple `WebAPI` project in `asp.net core`. I created a docker file for my project but I got the following error:

```sh
No executable found matching command "api.dll"
```

I've manually published the project by the following command and based on that I created a simple docker file.

```sh
dotnet publish -c Release -o ./app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet AS base

WORKDIR /test/app
COPY ./app .

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet" , "api.dll" ]
```

when I ran the project by manually mounting the folders and files it works just fine:

```sh
docker run --rm -it -p 9090:80 -v /path/to/my/publish/folder:/test/app microsoft/dotnet
```

However, when I create an image based on the above-mentioned docker file

```sh
docker build -t myapp/test:dev .
```

and then attepting to create a container based on the image I got an error

```sh
docker run -it -p 9090:80 myapp/test:dev
```

and the error is :

```sh
No executable found matching command "api.dll"
```

What's wrong with my approach? anyone can help?

**PS:** I am running on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check casing of api.dll and if it is not working try to add "./" before

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet AS base

WORKDIR /test/app
COPY ./app .

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet" , "./api.dll" ]
```

Comment: I did not want to copy the source to intermediate containers, the approach you mentioned works since it compiles the project in the intermediary containers and then creates the final version. And I did not get your point that my docker file missed the `dotnet`

Comment: If it is the case then check casing of api.dll , mentioning Api.dll as api.dll will cause No executable found matching command "api.dll".Can you check and confirm?

Comment: Sure, hold on a minute.

Comment: Updated my answer, try it